# Change from Km to Miles in CLLocationDistance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have currently this setup and I would love to change from Km to Miles in calculating distance. Here's my current code:

```
CLLocation *userloc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];

CLLocationDistance distance2 = [userloc distanceFromLocation:loc]/ 1000;
NSLog(@"%f",distance2);

[distance setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", distance2]];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a simple conversion:

```
CLLocationDistance distance2 = [userloc distanceFromLocation:loc] * 0.000621371;
NSLog(@"%f",distance2);

[distance setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f mi", distance2]];
```

Comment: You are welcome. As a newcomer, don't forget to accept an answer that solves your problem by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Ups! Thanks for that! Didn't know about accepting answers.... as you can see I am a newbie. ;)

Comment: use Measurement class